# How can I parse a string to a specific date format in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datetime, jquery-ui

**Parse a string to a specific date format in JavaScript.**

I will give input as a string(`date string`) and a date format(`string`).
Expecting output as date object.

I searched in stackoverflow and found some questions and answers.
I checked [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date) , [Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript/1056730#1056730) and [Converting a string to a date in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/converting-a-string-to-a-date-in-javascript)

But all are explaining about converting or formatting date to string.
I am looking for parsing a string to date object.

Here I will give date in string format. That is **input data is not a date object**. 
And giving format of date. Date format is giving dynamically. That is sometime it is `"MM/DD/YYYY"` or `'dd/mm/yy'` etc.
Expected output is date object.

*Example 1*

```
var string1 = '03/04/2019';
var format = 'dd/mm/yy';
var dateObject = parse(string1 , format );
```

*Example 2*

```
var string1 = '10/21/2013';
var format = 'MM/DD/YYYY';
var dateObject = parse(string1 , format );
```

Comment: I suggest you to use moment.js

Comment: Hi! look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/converting-a-string-to-a-date-in-javascript

Comment: I can not use external API in my project. Is there any method in JavaScript or JQuery  for above requirement.

Comment: You need to provide your own date parsing function. Hence it's almost always a good idea to store dates in ISO8601 notation: `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.ffffff` or as a unix timestamp integer. Both of these can natively be parsed by `new Date()` without the need to create a function that breaks up your own date format into the correct parameters to use with `new Date()`.

Comment: Durga : I checked your comment. In my case date format always different. It is not helped me. Thanks.

Comment: If you can't specify the date format at runtime then it's impossible to infer a date from your string.

Comment: Please look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55503943/9325419)